# PHP Store a list into array for generate report

Tags: php, arrays

I have a set of data from my survey result which look like below.

Member A
Service-1
Food-1
Like it?-1

Member B
Service-3
Food-2

Member C
Service-5
Food-4
Like it?-1

I wish to generate an array to store all the data above, and generate a report.

Example:
Food    1    1 Member Choose this
            2    3 Member Choose this
            4    0 Member Choose this

Please help......

Except array, do I have any other way to generate this?

Comment: To make it short: No.

Comment: Are data originally contained in a multidimensional array? I see the second element has "Like it" item missing: is it optional?

Comment: @Giorgio yes, the data is from an json. The second element missing "Like it" because the member skipped the question.

Comment: What does it mean "0" in the second result column? I supposed it was referred to "service" value, so I expected to find "5" for the third element...

Comment: @Giorgio sorry,my mistake. but this is just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to have exactly understood the question. Supposing that

- results should be shown in a table form
- the second column of results is service number
- the third column is a simple text (not related to members id)

you can try this

```
/* Create sample data (you may use json_decode) */
$memberA = array('member'=>'A', 'service'=>'1', 'food'=>'1', 'like'=>'1');
$memberB = array('member'=>'B', 'service'=>'3', 'food'=>'2', 'like'=>'');
$memberC = array('member'=>'C', 'service'=>'5', 'food'=>'4', 'like'=>'3');
$members = array($memberA, $memberB, $memberC);

/* Build new array */
$results = array();
foreach($members as $member)
{
    $item = array('food'=>$member['food'], 'service'=>$member['service']);
    array_push($results, $item);
}

/* Output results */
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><td>Food</td><td>Service</td><td>Notes</td></tr>';
foreach($results as $result)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'. $result['food'] . '</td><td>' . $result['service'] . '</td><td>Member choose this</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

In this example I've created sample data as an array for simplicity. If you have json source, you can transform it in a PHP variable with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function.

**Note**

If your goal is to simply output data (you don't need to use `$results` array again), you can print them directly in the first `foreach` cycle, without creating `$results` variable.